# Переустановка без использования загрузочной флешки удалит вирусы?

Tags: windows, вирусы, пк

Лень создавать загрузочную флешку. Комп включается, работает, но вирусы есть. Хотел переустановить через media creation tool. Такой способ поможет избавиться от вирусов?

Comment: Зависит от того, какие вирусы. От одних достаточно их файлы удалить, от других может понадобиться выпаивать из материнки флеш-память биоса и перепрошивать программатором

Comment: ну, все конечно, не настолько ужасно, что надо будет биос перепрошивать) вопрос в том, есть ли разница между переустановкой через загрузочный носитель и media creation tool? результат будет одинаковым?

Comment: По прошлому опыту могу сказать, что накатывать винду поверх винды - очень сомнительное занятие. И чистую свежую не получишь и старое так себе переносится. Используй проверенные методы: фсё важное файло на `D:\\`, закладки браузера в облаке.

Comment: Ок, понял. Тогда такой вопрос: если создать загрузочную флешку прямо на этом (зараженном) компьютере, и с неё  же начать переустановку, то вирусы могут появиться на чистой системе? Так сказать, с флешки перейти